# Python Selenium : Xpath element not found

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I'm trying to click on a part of a webpage, but I'm getting the message "NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element"....despite the element is there.

The code used to work, however it looks like there was a change in the page..but the xpath did not changed.

I tried different solutions of similar questions here in Stackoverflow, but something is not correct yet for this example.

The URL is:
"http://www.bmfbovespa.com.br/pt_br/servicos/market-data/consultas/mercado-a-vista/codigo-isin/pesquisa/"

The element I`m trying to click : "Download de Arquivos"

My code:

```
from selenium import webdriver 


fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
fp.set_preference("browser.download.folderList",2)
fp.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting",False)
fp.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/msword, application/csv, application/vnd.ms-excel, application/ris, text/csv, image/png, application/pdf, text/html, text/plain, application/zip, application/x-zip, application/x-zip-compressed, application/download, application/octet-stream")
fp.set_preference('browser.helperApps.alwaysAsk.force', False) 



driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=fp)
driver.get("http://www.bmfbovespa.com.br/pt_br/servicos/market-data/consultas/mercado-a-vista/codigo-isin/pesquisa/")

###
# Click "Download de arquivos" (the part with problem)
###

elem=driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='ctl00_contentPlaceHolderConteudo_rtsDetalhe_tabDownload']/span/span")
elem.click()
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple options here:

- locate the link "by id":

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_contentPlaceHolderConteudo_rtsDetalhe_tabDownload")
  ```
- by link text via the "by xpath" locator:

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[span/span = 'Download de Arquivos']")
  ```

And, the important part is that the element is inside an `iframe` - you need to switch to it.

Working code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.bmfbovespa.com.br/pt_br/servicos/market-data/consultas/mercado-a-vista/codigo-isin/pesquisa/")

driver.switch_to.frame("bvmf_iframe")

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
elem = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "ctl00_contentPlaceHolderConteudo_rtsDetalhe_tabDownload")))
elem.click()
```

Comment: I tried both....but I'm still getting the "NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element:" message.